# Resharper plugin to sort the methods alphabetically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sorting, resharper-4.5

Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a free plugin called **Menees VS Tools 2022** (supports Visual Studio 2022) that allows you to sort the members of a type alphabetically:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BillMenees.MeneesVSTools2022&ssr=false#overview

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Resharper has it, but [MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v6/mztools6.aspx) does.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize settings in resharper as explained here:
[Resharper Clean-up Code - how to affect sorting of methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509244/resharper-clean-up-code-how-to-affect-sorting-of-methods)

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

To clean up an interface by sorting alphabetically you can also create a class diagram with the interface, select all methods, cut and paste into the same class - and you're done.