# Is there a Visual Studio 2010 extension to sort methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coding-style, stylecop, visual-studio-extensions

[StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) mandates a particular sort order for the contents of C# files. For example, fields should be declared before methods and public declarations should come before private ones.

It would be useful to have a Visual Studio extension to move these things into that order automatically.

Does a *good* extension exist for this (I've found [CodeSorter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3482faf3-5519-4df9-afb1-c66f184766ac?SRC=VSIDE), but the feedback suggests it's very buggy)? Or are there any extensions or shortcuts that make it less painful to reorder this content manually?

Comment: Sounds like a make-work silly rule if you ask me.

Comment: I believe the idea is to present information in decreasing order of importance so that someone reading it (i.e. intending to use it) can get to grips with it more quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try with [Regionerate](http://www.rauchy.net/regionerate/docs/2007/05/download.html) :

> Regionerate is an automated tool which helps you to preserve your
>   code's layout over time. Regionerate lets you define regions in your
>   code and determine the way members (fields, methods, properties etc.)
>   should be placed inside them. Regionerate is a zero-friction tool -
>   when setting up, you can choose a Code Layout (the way you want your
>   code to look) or just use the default Code Layout. From that moment
>   on, Regionerate will make sure your code follows that Code Layout.

Answer (score 6):

ReSharper can do this. It has a "Type Members Layout" feature that allows you to use either a default set of rules, or to define your own.

Comment: After some searching I found [this blog post](http://blog.mijalko.com/2009/01/resharper-stylecop-and-type-members.html) that gives a set of ReSharper rules for this very scenario.

Answer (score 5):

CodeMaid is a free and open source Visual Studio extension that will reorganize code to follow StyleCop conventions.  You can find it here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496

Disclaimer:  This is a totally shameless plug, I wrote it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I use ReSharper and their Type Member Layout. See my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8599288/568266) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If Code Sorting is your only concern, you can try the Visual Studio Extension [CodeSorter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3482faf3-5519-4df9-afb1-c66f184766ac)

> CodeSorter is highly customizable extension that allows its users to
>   sort C# code itby various conditions such as names, types (method,
>   class, struct, ...), visibility modifiers (private, public, ...),
>   constness modifiers (const, static, readonly) and virtuality modifiers
>   (virtual, override, new, ...).
>
> It is possible to assign multiple search criteria to have the same
>   priority, for example place protected and private members first, and
>   then publics and internals.
>
> Names are compared in a way that leading "m_" and "_" is stripped.
>   This allows fields and properties (eg. _foo and Foo) to be right next
>   to each other.
>
> One-lined declarations are placed without delimiting blank line, while
>   multi-lined declarations are separated by a blank line. The exception
>   is that one-lined field followed by a multi-lined property without
>   comment of the same name will be placed without the delimiting blank
>   line.

Comment: I mentioned CodeSorter in the question.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge my mistake. I've been using it for long, and haven't faced any bugs so far.