# Sorting source code

Tags: editor, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way to sort (format) methods/properties/variables/constans in a class or interface in alphabetical by type order in the source code.

Inside the Visual Studio 2013 editor?

More than format selection or 
format document

Plugin?

Comment: You can use Resharper. 
Have a look in this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509244/resharper-clean-up-code-how-to-affect-sorting-of-methods

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alphabetizing methods in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466417/alphabetizing-methods-in-visual-studio)